# How to create a graph using nx.read_edgelist if my csv file is present at S3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, networkx

I have a csv file located at one of my S3 bucket (s3://abc/FB/train_woheader.csv).
When I write..

```
g=nx.read_edgelist('s3://abc/FB/train_woheader.csv',delimiter=',',create_using=nx.DiGraph(),nodetype=int, encoding='utf-8')
print(nx.info(g))
```

it says

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 's3://abc/FB/train_woheader.csv'
```

However, if I save the csv in the Jupyter instance then I am able to create the graph using the line

```
g=nx.read_edgelist('train_woheader.csv',delimiter=',',create_using=nx.DiGraph(),nodetype=int, encoding='utf-8')
```

The csv is a heavy file and hence needs to be saved in S3 only. It can't be saved in Jupyter instance as its eats up a lot of space.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read_edgelist` is expecting to get a file or file name as [argument](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.read_edgelist.html#read-edgelist).
What you can do is to read the file from s3 (using boto3),
use StringIO and pass the populated file to read_edgelis:

```
import io.StringIO()
with io.StringIO() as f
    f.write('data_coming_from_s3_using_boto3')
    f.seek(0)
    g=nx.read_edgelist(f,delimiter=',',create_using=nx.DiGraph(),nodetype=int, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks but can you explain what the 'data_coming_from_s3_using_boto3' should be like? Is it something like this  

`import boto3

bucketname = '<bucket-name>'
itemname = '<file-name>'

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object(bucketname, itemname)
data_coming_from_s3_using_boto3 = obj.get()['Body'].read()`

Comment: Yes. This the direction!

Comment: Thanks a ton! This approach worked. My data was in Bytes and hence, instead of StringIO, BytesIO worked.